# Trying to replace text from config file to broadcast, and getting 'Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to String'

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

When trying to make a broadcast code line that reads the message it will send from config, I need to replace multiple things in one line, but I get the error described in title.

I've tried to change string to int, but it gives errors on my other parts. Please help me fix, see code below and debug what is wrong. THANK YOU!

```java
if(plugin.getConfig().getBoolean("enable_global_death")) {
                        String bc = Bukkit.broadcastMessage(Utils.chat(plugin.getConfig().getString("global_death")));
                          bc = bc.replace("<killer>", killer.getName());        
                          bc = bc.replace("<player>", p.getName());
                          bc = bc.replace("<kill_weapon>", (CharSequence) killer.getItemInHand());

                        return;
```

I expected the output to not have any errors, I expected it to replace the things in config such as  to the name of the killer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You habe to replace the strings first before you broadcast your Message:

```java
if(plugin.getConfig().getBoolean("enable_global_death")) {
    String bc = Utils.chat(plugin.getConfig().getString("global_death"));
    bc = bc.replace("<killer>", killer.getName());        
    bc = bc.replace("<player>", p.getName());
    bc = bc.replace("<kill_weapon>", killer.getItemInHand().getType().toString());
    Bukkit.broadcastMessage(bc);
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't tell which line causes the exception to be thrown. But I assume that it's the last `bc = bc.replace(…)` line and that `killer.getItemInHand()` returns a number (`int`, I guess). If my assumptions are correct, then the following should help:

Method `String.replace(…)` accepts two parameters of type `CharSequence`. But if `killer.getItemInHand()` returns a number, you cannot just cast it to `CharSequence`. Java doesn't know how to do it. You have to convert the number to a `CharSequence` (or a subtype, such as `String`) explicitly:

```
bc.replace("<kill_weapon>", String.valueOf(killer.getItemInHand()));
```

Comment: Oh sorry for the lack of info. I get the error on the first line.

Comment: OK, what is the return type of method `getName()` (that you call in `killer.getName()`)?

Comment: What is important is the return type of method Player.getName(). The name suggests that it might be `String` but it is necessary to know the type for sure.

Comment: oh, it is a string.

Comment: Well, I understood that the exception is thrown from the line with `bc.replace("<killer>", killer.getName());`. But this line seems to be correct. I am not able to identify exactly the exact spot where the error happens without further information. My current guess is that the error happens during compilation because the expression `Bukkit.broadcastMessage(…)` returns `int` and you try to cast it to `String`, which is invalid. Java doesn't know how to cast `int` to `String`.